# Is lock necessary when GOMAXPROCS is 1

Tags: go

> The `GOMAXPROCS` variable limits the number of operating system
>   threads that can execute user-level Go code simultaneously.

So, if `GOMAXPROCS` is 1, no matter how many goroutines I have, it is safe to access variable (like `map`) from different goroutines  without any lock. Correct?

Comment: No. Go routines and threads are quite different things and concurrent access means you cannot guarantee the order of execution; locks and/or channels are still required.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is, "no" it is not safe. The long answer is really too long to explain in enough detail here, but I'll give a short summary and some links to articles which should help you put the pieces together.

Let's differentiate between "concurrent" and "parallel" first. Consider two functions. Running in parallel they can both be executing at the same instant on separate processors. Running concurrently either, or both, or neither *may* be executing but both are *able* to execute. If they are concurrent but not parallel then they are switching—and without channels or locks we cannot guarantee the sequence in terms of which gets where first.

It may be weird to think about "concurrent but not parallel" but consider that the opposite is quite unremarkable, parallel but not concurrent; my text editor, terminal and browser are all running in parallel but are most definitely not concurrent.

So if two (or 20,000) functions have access to the same memory, say one writes and one reads, and they are running concurrently, then perhaps the write happens first, perhaps the read happens first. There are no guarantees unless we take responsibility for the scheduling/sequencing, hence locks and channels.

Setting GOMAXSPROCS to greater than 1 makes it possible for a concurrent program to run in parallel, but it may not, all *concurrent* goroutines may be on one CPU thread, or they may be on multiple. Thus setting GOMAXPROCS to 1 is no guarantee that concurrent processes are safe without locks or channels to orchestrate their execution.

Threads are [typically] scheduled by the operating system. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29) or your favorite repository of human knowledge. Goroutines are scheduled by Go.

Next consider this:

> Even with [a] single logical processor and operating system thread, hundreds of thousands of goroutines can be scheduled to run concurrently with amazing efficiency and performance.

and this:

> The problem with building concurrency into our applications is eventually our goroutines are going to attempt to access the same resources, possibly at the same time. Read and write operations against a shared resource must always be atomic. In other words reads and writes must happen by one goroutine at a time or else we create race conditions in our programs.

from  [this article](https://www.goinggo.net/2014/01/concurrency-goroutines-and-gomaxprocs.html), which explains the difference really well and references some other material you may want to look up (the article is somewhat outdated, as GMAXPROCS no longer defaults to 1, but the general theory is still accurate).

And finally, Effective Go can be daunting when you're starting out but is a must-read. [Here](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#concurrency) is the explanation of concurrency in Go.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, locks are still needed, even if you are running your program on one processor. Concurrency and Parallelism are different things, you'll find a very good explanation [here](https://www.goinggo.net/2014/01/concurrency-goroutines-and-gomaxprocs.html).

Just a little example here:

```
func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)

    t := &test{}

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
            // Some computation prior to using t.Num
            time.Sleep(300 * time.Microsecond)
            num := t.Num
            // Some computation using num
            time.Sleep(300 * time.Microsecond)
            t.Num = num + 1
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
            num := t.Num
            // Some computation using num
            time.Sleep(300 * time.Microsecond)
            t.Num = num + 1
        }
    }()

    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second) // Wait goroutines to finish

    fmt.Println(t.Num)

}
```

The sleeping time is there to represent some computation which takes some time. I wanted to keep the example runnable and simple, that's why I used it.

When running this, even on a single processor, the output is not 200 as we want to. So yes, locks are necessary when accessing variables concurrently, or you'll run into problems.

Comment: If we don't care about the sum result,  we just don't want any panic. In that case, is setting thread number to 1 good enough?

Answer (score 0):

Changing state, with `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)` assumed, will fail; even for just two go-routines:

```
func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)

    start := make(chan struct{})
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}

    N := 2 //10, 1000, 10000, ... fails with even 2 go-routines

    for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)

        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            <-start

            //processing state
            initialState := globalState

            //give another goroutine a chance, by halting this one
            //and lend some processing cycles
            //(also simulating "concurrent" processing of initialState)
            runtime.Gosched()

            if globalState != initialState {
                panic(fmt.Sprintf("oops! %d != %d", initialState, globalState))
            }
            globalState = initialState + 1
        }()
    }

    close(start)
    wg.Wait()

    log.Println(`global state:`, globalState)
}

var (
    globalState int
)
```

Other answers went more into details - good for studying different aspects of concurrent programming.